# Access value inside finalize pipe from test

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I have component:

```
isLoading: boolean;
users: User[];
test: number = 1;

ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.userService.getUsers()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          // Disable loading when complete
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.test = 5;
        })
      )
  .subscribe(results => {this.users = results})
}
```

And I have test for it (.spec.ts)

```
    it('should be 5 after ngOnInit', () => {
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.test).toBe(5);
    });
```

I am getting an error for test 'Expected 1 to be 5.'
Why there is this error, if I read value after ngOnInit, .finalize is ignored? How do I get value from .finalize block. fixture.detectChanges() does not help also.

Comment: Have you created a mock of getUsers() that’s an observable that completes? If you haven’t, it will never reach finalize in the test.

Comment: How have you stubbed the userService.getUsers() method in your test? Do you realize that finalize() will only be called once the observable returned by getUsers() completes. Which will be much later than when ngOnInit() returns if the observable is asynchronous?

Comment: Mock should be done using spy? I try this code and now test is passed: spy = spyOn(usersService, 'getUsers').and.returnValue(of(new User[]));

Answer (score 0):

It can be tested like this:

```
it('should set test value to 5', () => {
        const userService= TestBed.get(UserService);

        userService.getUsers()
            .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    expect(component.test).toEqual(5);
                } )
            )
    });
```

I used mock for the service:

```
class MockUserService {
    getUsers(): Observable<number> {
        return of(1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

And in configureTestingModule

```
            {provide: UserService , useValue: new MockUserService ()}
```

Comment: this doesn't test `ngOnInit`, though.